# How to reference method without calling it?

Tags: python

How to reference method of class in Python?

In PHP there is so called "callable", pretty much an array with two elements, where first is FQCN or object instance, second is method name e.g.:

`$callable = [$this, 'methodName']`

or with FQCN

`$callable = [\My\Namespaced\Foo::class, 'methodName']`

Following is very important for me. It is possible to invoke it later e.g. by:

`call_user_func($callable);`

How to get same in Python and what is the Pythonic name for it?

Comment: A method is just like *any other attribute*. `my_instance.some_method` references the method without calling it. To call it, you woudl use parentheses, i.e. `my_instance.some_method()`. This has no particular name. There is no special treatment of methods/functions in python. They are just regular objects, like any other  (e.g. `int`, `str`, `dict` etc etc)

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding what you're asking. Can you please edit your question to add some examples? Does what @juanpa.arrivillaga comments solve your doubt?

Comment: `call_user_func = my_instance.some_method; call_user_func(x)` is equivalent to `my_instance.some_method(x)`. `call_user_func` refers to what is called a *bound method*.

Comment: In your example you seem to be referencing methods by a combination of the object and the string name of the method. If it is important to get the reference from a string, maybe you are looking for `getattr`. For example,  if `s` is a string object then `getattr(s,'upper')`  returns a reference to `s.upper`

Comment: The thing actually called isn't *quite* the same as the class attribute that stores the function. There are some subtleties involving the descriptor protocol that you don't really need to worry about, though, in order to make use of bound methods.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga can you please turn your comment into an answer? This helped me most and it resolved my issue. Will gladly acept it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can get (via the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)) something called a bound method.

```
class A:
    def foo(self, x):
        print(x)


a = A()
f = a.foo
f(3)  # Equivalent to a.foo(3)
```

`f` is a bound method, an object very much (it seems) like the array you describe in PHP. The bound method `f` is little more than an object that contains references to `a` and `A.foo`, so that when you call `f(...)`, it basically just calls `A.foo(a, ...)` for you.